# PC stuck during boot when booted with microSD card inserted

Tags: windows-10, boot, sd-card, micro-sd-card

I have a PC with 32GB eMMC storage that I use for basic tasks. Also, a 128GB microSD card is used for storing stuffs. The PC was working fine till some hours back, but it won't boot up now.

My PC would get stuck during boot showing the manufacturer's logo if I boot it up keeping my SD card inserted. At first, I thought I made a mistake during disabling hibernation feature, but I eventually found that I didn't when I tried booting up the PC with the card pulled out.

Can anyone tell me why it is showing this peculiar behaviour?

**EDIT**: The problem has been fixed all on its own. Seems like a non-consistent bug of the manufacturer.

Comment: I want to add that since you indicate specifically "*showing the manufacturer's logo*" when it gets stuck with the microSD inserted, this is more than likely a hardware/firmware bug more than a Windows OS bug. If it's getting stuck on the manufacturer logo, then Windows hasn't loaded yet, and thus cannot be the problem. Download the latest BIOS/firmware updates for the make and model of your machine or motherboard experiencing the issue and see if that resolves. You should be able to read release notes for all versions released and see if the notes indicate about this issue being patched.

Answer (score 0):

This will be down to the boot order/boot priority in the BIOS. The BIOS is trying to boot an OS off the SD card, but then seemingly fails to try the next device. Check your BIOS boot order, and/or disable the boot from external/USB device(s).

Comment: While I appreciate your effort to solve the issue, but I would like to say that it has fixed on its own. Thank you for the help.